# SVN Restricting User to only add files to the Repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, user-permissions

I have a special case of repository production files.I need the users to only add/ download files to/from the repository. How should the user permission must be defined.

Answer (score 2):

Subversion doesn't have that granularity of permissions at this time.  The best option to do something like this would probably be a pre-commit hook script that reject commits that did more than you wanted.  I'd suggest reading the [Implementing Commit Hooks section of the SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) and also having a look at the templated pre-commit hook under your repositories hooks folder.

To implement this you're probably going to want to use the [svnlook command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnlook) which has the ability to look into the uncommitted transactions.